# How can you create a folder with PHP with special/wildcard characters?

Tags: php, filesystems, directory, specifications

I guess I have two questions actually:

**One:** How do I create folders with special/wildcard characters? (e.g. !@#$%^&*)

**Two:** How can I remove a folder created with those characters? I have two on my server and am using FTP and trying to remove them but they aren't being deleted.

I tried to rename them but Filezilla returns `550 234f @$%^: Forbidden command argument`. How can I remove them?

Comment: tried: rm <file name> from the command line

Comment: [Escaping and/or quoting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php). `!$&` all need special care from the commandline. If you do it with PHPs rmdir() the raw filename should be passed to the OS however.

Comment: assuming its a *nix server log in to the command line

Comment: Thanks @mario could you please post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Although @mario when I tried `escapeshellarg` it added single quotes around the text but it was cut off after "@".

Comment: Quite likely there might be another inivisable character. If all else fails try `foreach (glob("*@*") as $fn) { rmdir($fn); }` to remove anything which matches the undesired characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`escapeshellcmd()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) for escaping and or quoting. IF you want to execute the command on the console, single quotes usually do:

```
rmdir '550 234f @$%^'
```

If you can perform it from within PHP (if permissions are sufficient), then just use rmdir() as that passes the raw filename along to the operating system:

```
rmdir('550 234f @$%^');
```

In FTP clients the quoting or escaping might not always work; there's some variance in FTP server implementations.